# FixedDataTable with fixed column on right

Tags: reactjs, jsx, fixed-data-table

I have a collection of columns which all could be scrollable horizontally except last one, which should be fixed.

```
<Table ... >
      <Column
       ...
      />
      <Column
       ...
      />

      ...
      <Column
         fixed={true}
       ...
      />
</Table>
```

When it renders, the fixed column is always **left**, it does not matter the order of fixed columns in the table code.

Is is possible to have fixed column on right side?

I am using [FixedDataTable2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fixed-data-table-2) v 0.6.5